# Clarification on tf.Tensor.set_shape()

Tags: tensorflow

I have an image that is 478 x 717 x 3 = 1028178 pixels, with a rank of 1. I verified it by calling tf.shape and tf.rank.

When I call image.set_shape([478, 717, 3]), it throws the following error.

```
"Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other)) 
ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (478, 717, 3) must have the same rank
```

I tested again by first casting to 1028178, but the error still exists.

```
ValueError: Shapes (1028178,) and (478, 717, 3) must have the same rank
```

Well, that does make sense because one is of rank 1 and the other is of rank 3. However, why is it necessary to throw an error, as the total number of pixels still match.

I could of course use tf.reshape and it works, but I think that's not optimal.

As stated on the TensorFlow FAQ

> What is the difference between x.set_shape() and x = tf.reshape(x)?
>
> The tf.Tensor.set_shape() method updates the static shape of a Tensor
>   object, and it is typically used to provide additional shape
>   information when this cannot be inferred directly. It does not change
>   the dynamic shape of the tensor.
>
> The tf.reshape() operation creates a new tensor with a different dynamic shape.

Creating a new tensor involves memory allocation and that could potentially be more costly when more training examples are involved. Is this by design, or am I  missing something here?

Comment: The real question is whether reshaped Tensor shares the data buffer with original tensor, or whether it does a copy. I couldn't quite tell from quick reading of the code, but if it does a copy, that's something that should be fixed

Comment: mrry has elaborated that it's a shallow copy in his answer below.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As far as I know (and I wrote that code), there isn't a bug in [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape). I think the misunderstanding stems from the confusing name of that method.

To elaborate on the [FAQ entry you quoted](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/resources/faq.html#what_is_the_difference_between_xset_shape_and_x_tfreshapex), `Tensor.set_shape()` is a pure-Python function that *improves* the shape information for a given `tf.Tensor` object. By "improves", I mean "makes more specific".

Therefore, when you have a `Tensor` object `t` with shape `(?,)`, that is a one-dimensional tensor of unknown length. You can call `t.set_shape((1028178,))`, and then `t` will have shape `(1028178,)` when you call `t.get_shape()`. This doesn't affect the underlying storage, or indeed anything on the backend: it merely means that subsequent shape inference using `t` can rely on the assertion that it is a vector of length 1028178.

If `t` has shape `(?,)`, a call to `t.set_shape((478, 717, 3))` will fail, because TensorFlow already knows that `t` is a vector, so it *cannot* have shape `(478, 717, 3)`. If you want to make a new Tensor with that shape from the contents of `t`, you can use [`reshaped_t = tf.reshape(t, (478, 717, 3))`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape). This creates a new `tf.Tensor` object in Python; the actual [implementation of `tf.reshape()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/03bff43060229357cbe2cc1659e7d129c2799b06/tensorflow/core/kernels/reshape_op.h#L89) does this using a shallow copy of the tensor buffer, so it is inexpensive in practice.

One analogy is that `Tensor.set_shape()` is like a run-time cast in an object-oriented language like Java. For example, if you have a pointer to an `Object` but know that, in fact, it is a `String`, you might do the cast `(String) obj` in order to pass `obj` to a method that expects a `String` argument. However, if you have a `String` `s` and try to cast it to a `java.util.Vector`, the compiler will give you an error, because these two types are unrelated.

Comment: @merry do you know where the `set_shape()` functionality went in `1.0+`? I am looking for exactly this functionality in order to tell TensorFlow the shape of a result of `tf.py_func`.

Comment: It's still in the same place: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape

Comment: @mrry Great documentation on this method btw! I wanna give just that one 5*. But I am using the tf Dataset and after I pad/truncate some videos to 64 frames using .map() I get <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {video_input: (None, 32, 32, 3), label: ()}, types: {video_input: tf.float32, label: tf.int64}>. Shouldn't I be able to specify that videos are 64 frames long? Or does it just not matter for graph optimization?