# Tensorflow error: InvalidArgumentError: Different number of component types.

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to input batches of shuffled images to be training, and I write the code according to [the generic input images in TensorVision](https://github.com/TensorVision/TensorVision/blob/master/examples/inputs/generic_input.py), but I get an error. I cannot figure it where it is wrong.
This is my code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf


def read_labeled_image_list(image_list_file):
    """
    Read a .txt file containing pathes and labeles.
    Parameters
    ----------
     image_list_file : a .txt file with one /path/to/image per line
     label : optionally, if set label will be pasted after each line
    Returns
    -------
       List with all filenames in file image_list_file
    """
    f = open(image_list_file, 'r')
    filenames = []
    labels = []
    for line in f:
        filename, label = line[:-1].split(' ')
        filenames.append(filename)
        labels.append(int(label))
    return filenames, labels

def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):
    """Consumes a single filename and label as a ' '-delimited string.
    Parameters
    ----------
      filename_and_label_tensor: A scalar string tensor.
    Returns
    -------
      Two tensors: the decoded image, and the string label.
    """
    label = input_queue[1]
    file_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    example = tf.image.decode_png(file_contents, channels=3)
#    example = rescale_image(example)
    # processed_label = label
    return example, label

def random_resize(image, lower_size, upper_size):
    """Randomly resizes an image
    Parameters
    ----------
    lower_size:
    upper_size:
    Returns
    -------
      a randomly resized image
    """

    new_size = tf.to_int32(
        tf.random_uniform([], lower_size, upper_size))

    return tf.image.resize_images(image, new_size, new_size,
                                  method=0)
def _input_pipeline(filename, batch_size,
                    processing_image=lambda x: x,
                    processing_label=lambda y: y,
                    num_epochs=None):
    """The input pipeline for reading images classification data.
    The data should be stored in a single text file of using the format:
     /path/to/image_0 label_0
     /path/to/image_1 label_1
     /path/to/image_2 label_2
     ...
     Args:
       filename: the path to the txt file
       batch_size: size of batches produced
       num_epochs: optionally limited the amount of epochs
    Returns:
       List with all filenames in file image_list_file
    """

    # Reads pfathes of images together with there labels
    image_list, label_list = read_labeled_image_list(filename)

    images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=tf.string)
    labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=tf.int32)

    # Makes an input queue
    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels],
                                                num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                                shuffle=True)

    # Reads the actual images from
    image, label = read_images_from_disk(input_queue)
    pr_image = processing_image(image)
    pr_label = processing_label(label)

    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([pr_image, pr_label],
                                              batch_size=batch_size, 
                                              shapes = [256,256,3])

    # Display the training images in the visualizer.
    tensor_name = image.op.name
    tf.image_summary(tensor_name + 'images', image_batch)
    return image_batch, label_batch
def test_pipeline():
    data_folder = '/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/data/UCLandUsedImages/'
    data_file = 'UCImage_Labels.txt'

    filename = os.path.join(data_folder, data_file)

    image_batch, label_batch = _input_pipeline(filename, 75)

    # Create the graph, etc.
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    a = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    print("Finish Test")
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    aa = test_preprocc()
#    matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(aa[1])
    a1 = test_pipeline()
    a2 = test_pipeline()
```

but it comes out an error, it confuses me for a long time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-e24901ce3365>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced/readUClandUsedImagetxt1.py', wdir='/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced/readUClandUsedImagetxt1.py", line 254, in <module>
    a1 = test_pipeline()

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced/readUClandUsedImagetxt1.py", line 244, in test_pipeline
    a = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 659, in _do_call
    e.code)

InvalidArgumentError: Different number of component types.  Types: uint8, int32, Shapes: [[256,256,3]]
     [[Node: batch_11/fifo_queue = FIFOQueue[capacity=32, component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], container="", shapes=[[256,256,3]], shared_name="", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'batch_11/fifo_queue', defined at:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to wrong argument `shapes` for function [`tf.train.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch). The argument `shapes` should be left to default, or should be:

> shapes: (Optional) The shapes for each example. Defaults to the inferred shapes for tensor_list

Here you are giving `shapes = [256, 256, 3]`, but you should give the shape for `pr_image` and `pr_label` in a list:

```py
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
    [pr_image, pr_label],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shapes = [[256,256,3], pr_label.get_shape()])
```

Comment: Yeah. I think it is this reason. I change it and it comes out another error OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_9_batch_2/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 15, current size 0)  I think  it may due to the input dataset is exhausted. Is there anyway to output a list of the shuffled batches and labels?

Comment: It raises the error after the correct number of epochs `num_epochs`?

Comment: After I set a proper 'num_epochs',  i.e. 'num_epochs*batch_size = num_traningsamples', it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: But when I try to change into `shapes = [pr_image.get_shape(), pr_label.get_shape()]` it cannot define the shape of image: `ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([])]`. What is the reason here?

Comment: I think the reason is similar to [Clarification on tf.set_shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451948/clarification-on-tf-set-shape/35464950#35464950)

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't know in advance the shape of your images. You have to set it by hand (if they all have the same fixed size) or resize them in Tensorflow

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.