# Why and when does the tensor's shape information unspecific?

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, tensor

I found piece of code like this:

```
y = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps + 1],
                     [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps + 1])
y.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])
```

as [Clarification on tf.Tensor.set_shape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451948/clarification-on-tf-tensor-set-shape) said, set_shape can make the shape information more specific. But why data's shape information here is not specific? When does the tensor's information unspecific?